# Running NodeJS app: type: error, code:forbidden

Tags: node.js

I am a newcomer to NodeJS and have been following a simple tutorial. Here is my code

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write("Hey, I am a dinosaur!");
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
console.log("Listening on Port 8080");
```

But when I start the server and go to localhost:8080, I receive the following

```
{
    "type" : "error",
    "code" : "Forbidden"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps you have another service running on port 8080 already?

Comment: When you run the code does it log `Listening on Port 8080`?